# Share large photo from FB album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I'm creating a web app where I'd like to 1) upload a photo to an app-specific album on Facebook and then 2) share that photo as a LARGE item/image (not a thumbnail) on the users' Timeline. I know this is doable via User Generated Photo optional parameter but is there any other way to accomplish this for a web app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos + https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping web apps from publishing Open Graph actions with User Generated Photos. It's a simple process:

1. Setup Facebook auth on your site, your simplest option being to [use the Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) with getLoginStatus. Make sure to request `publish_actions` permission from users.
2. [Create an Open Graph action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/) and your [OG object types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/)
3. When the user takes the appropriate action, make an API call of the following form (signed with the user access token and POST'd):
   `https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE:YOUR_APP_ACTION?
   YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE=YOUR_OBJECT_URL&
   image[0][url]=YOUR_PHOTO_URL&
   image[0][user_generated]=true`

Step 1 is the hardest part and you'd have to do that anyway if you weren't going down the Open Graph actions route.

As an example, Instagram use `took` as their action and `a photo` as their object. Their objects URLs are simply the individual photo pages on the Instagram website. So their API POST call would look like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/instagram:took?
  photo=http://instagram.com/p/ABCD1234/&
  image[0][url]=http://distilleryimage.instagram.com/somerandomstring.jpg&
  image[0][user_generated]=true`

As mentioned in the [User Generated Photos documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/) this will show up as a large, full-width photo on the users Timeline and feed.

The simplest way to perform all these API calls from a web app is to use the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and the [FB.api function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/). You won't need to use any server-side code at all in that case!

Answer (score 0):

Just fill this code on your photo caption

"took a @@[0:[124024574287414:1:photo]] with @[124024574287414:0]"

(without double quote symbol)
It clickable to instagram website, It's my own custom code, I made it for a week :(